# Code after while loop terminates does not run

Tags: c, sorting, while-loop

I am writing an algorithm that will sort a linkedlist. However I am running into issues where it appears that my while loops has terminate, but none of the following code would run. I may very well be wrong about my while loop terminating, but according to my printouts the condition for the while loop (cur!=NULL) has been met.

```
void LL_sort (struct node **headpp){
//if list is null or size 1
if((*headpp)==NULL || (*headpp)->next ==NULL){
    return;
}
struct node* sortedHead = NULL;
struct node* sortedCur = NULL;
struct node* cur = *headpp;
struct node* fwd = (*headpp)->next;
int emptyflag = 0;

while(cur!=NULL){
    fwd=cur->next;
    printf("start of loop cur is %p wtih value %i\n", cur, cur->data);
    printf("start of loop fwd is %p\n", fwd);
    //if sorted list is empty
    if(sortedHead == NULL){
        cur->next = NULL;
        sortedHead = cur;
        emptyflag = 1;
        printf("[sorted list NULL]sorted head is %p with value %i\n", sortedHead, sortedHead->data );
        printf("[sorted list NULL]reg head is %p with value %i\n", *headpp, (*headpp)->data );
    }
    //if cur is smaller than head
    if(sortedHead->data >= cur->data && emptyflag==0){
        cur->next = sortedHead;
        sortedHead = cur;
        printf("[sortedHead change]sorted head is %p with value %i\n", sortedHead, sortedHead->data );
        printf("[sortedHead change]reg head is %p with value %i\n", *headpp, (*headpp)->data );
    }

    sortedCur=sortedHead;
    printf("sortedCur is %p with value %i\n",sortedCur, sortedCur->data );
    printf("sortedCur->next is %p \n",sortedCur->next );
    printf("sortedhead is %p with value %i\n",sortedHead, sortedHead->data );
    printf("sortedHead->next is %p \n",sortedHead->next );
    while((sortedCur->next!=NULL) && (sortedCur->data < cur->data)){
        sortedCur=sortedCur->next;
    }
    if(sortedCur->next == NULL && emptyflag ==0){
        sortedCur->next = cur;
        sortedCur->next = NULL;
    }

    if(sortedCur->data < cur->data && emptyflag ==0){
        sortedCur->next = cur;
        cur->next = sortedCur->next->next;
    }
    emptyflag=0;

    cur = fwd;

    printf("end of loop cur is %p\n", cur);
    printf("end of loop cur has value %i\n", cur->data);
    printf("end of loop sortedHead is %p\n", sortedHead);
    printf("end of loop sortedHead has value %i\n", sortedHead->data);
    printf("end of loop sortedHead->next is %p \n", sortedHead->next);
    printf(" -------------------------------------------------- \n");
  }

  printf("this won't print\n");
  *headpp=sortedHead;
  }
```

I expected the loop to finish and the head of the linked list be changed to the sorted one so that any following functions calling for the list would yield a sorted list.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger, like gdb?  If not this would be a good time to learn; then you can see exactly what is executing when.  Make sure to compile your code with `-O0 -g` which will help make debugging easier.

Comment: Also, what exactly is the output you *do* get?  How is the linked list initialized?

Comment: I get all the print outs up until the very last iteration of the while loop. It even runs   printf("end of loop cur is %p\n", cur); which shows me that cur is 0000000 which i assume is NULL. I assumed once cur is NULL the loop ends but this line of code still runs.

Answer (score 2):

if `cur` is `NULL` then this line

```
printf("end of loop cur has value %i\n", cur->data);
```

invokes undefined behaviour by dereferencing `NULL`. Anything can happen then and it is very likely the program just crashed.

Comment: That is most likely it as well, though OP didn't what happens to the rest of their program.  I would assume it segfaults or something, eventually.

Answer (score 0):

As [@alk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694576/alk) already mentioned, this line can lead to a segmentation fault.

```
printf("end of loop cur has value %i\n", cur->data);
```

Change it to something like:

```
if (cur != NULL)
    printf("end of loop cur has value %i\n", cur->data);
```

Your function works just fine. The head of the linked list is changed to the sorted one.
I used this program to test it:

```
int main(){
    // Create the head node
    struct node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->next = NULL;
    head->data = 10;

    // Create 9 more nodes, 10 in total
    struct node *ptr = head;
    int i;
    for (i = 9; i > 0; i--){
        ptr->next = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        ptr->next->next = NULL;
        ptr->next->data = i;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    // Print all the nodes
    ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL){
        printf("Node: %p, Next: %p, Data: %d\n", ptr, ptr->next, ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    LL_sort(&head);

    // Print the sorted nodes
    ptr = head;
    while (ptr != NULL){
        printf("Node: %p, Next: %p, Data: %d\n", ptr, ptr->next, ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```